# Pandas merge error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, typeerror

I have a dataset with several tables, each in the form of countries, years, and some indicators. I have converted all the excel tables to csv files, then merged them into one table.

The problem is that I have some tables that refuse to be merged, and the following message appears `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`
I tried everything I can, but no luck, still the same error appears!
Also, I tried with hundreds of different files, but there are still tens of files that face this problem.

For the sample files [file17.csv](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1jUsbr5pw6sUMvewI4fmbpssroG4RZ7LE&export=download) and [file35.csv](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1Ufx6pvnSC6zQdTAj05ObmV027fA4-Mr3&export=download)  (In case someone needs to repeat it). *Here are the code I used:*

```
# To load the first file
import pandas as pd
filename1 = 'file17.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(filename1, encoding='cp1252', low_memory=False)
df1.set_index(['Country', 'Year'], inplace=True)
df1.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
df1.head()
```

Out>>>

```
+-------------+------+--------+--------+
|             |      | ind500 | ind356 |
| Country     | Year |        |        |
| Afghanistan | 1800 | 603.0  | NaN    |
|             | 1801 | 603.0  | NaN    |
|             | 1802 | 603.0  | NaN    |
|             | 1803 | 603.0  | NaN    |
|             | 1804 | 603.0  | NaN    |
+-------------+------+--------+--------+
```

In>>>

```
# To load the second file
filename2 = 'file35.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, encoding='cp1252', low_memory=False)
df2.set_index(['Country', 'Year'], inplace=True)
df2.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
df2.head()
```

Out>>>

[image]

```
# To merge the two dataframes
gross_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
gross_df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
print (gross_df.shape)
gross_df.to_csv('merged.csv')
```

**Important notice:** 
I noticed that in all the successful files, the columns names appear in ascending orders i.e. `ind001`, `ind009`, `ind012`, as they were sorted automatically. while the files with errors have one or more columns with misordered placement like `ind500` followed by `in356` in the first table and the same applies to the second sample provided.

Notice that the two dataframesindiceswo indices (`Country` and `year`)

**The error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in safe_sort(values, labels, na_sentinel, assume_unique)
    480         try:
--> 481             sorter = values.argsort()
    482             ordered = values.take(sorter)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-960b2698de60> in <module>()
----> 1 gross_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', sort=False)
      2 gross_df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
      3 print (gross_df.shape)
      4 gross_df.to_csv('merged.csv')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator)
     52                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
     53                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
---> 54     return op.get_result()
     55 
     56 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in get_result(self)
    567                 self.left, self.right)
    568 
--> 569         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    570 
    571         ldata, rdata = self.left._data, self.right._data

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_info(self)
    720             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \
    721                 left_ax.join(right_ax, how=self.how, return_indexers=True,
--> 722                              sort=self.sort)
    723         elif self.right_index and self.how == 'left':
    724             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers, sort)
   2995             else:
   2996                 return self._join_non_unique(other, how=how,
-> 2997                                              return_indexers=return_indexers)
   2998         elif self.is_monotonic and other.is_monotonic:
   2999             try:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _join_non_unique(self, other, how, return_indexers)
   3076         left_idx, right_idx = _get_join_indexers([self.values],
   3077                                                  [other._values], how=how,
-> 3078                                                  sort=True)
   3079 
   3080         left_idx = _ensure_platform_int(left_idx)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
    980 
    981     # get left & right join labels and num. of levels at each location
--> 982     llab, rlab, shape = map(list, zip(* map(fkeys, left_keys, right_keys)))
    983 
    984     # get flat i8 keys from label lists

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _factorize_keys(lk, rk, sort)
   1409     if sort:
   1410         uniques = rizer.uniques.to_array()
-> 1411         llab, rlab = _sort_labels(uniques, llab, rlab)
   1412 
   1413     # NA group

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _sort_labels(uniques, left, right)
   1435     labels = np.concatenate([left, right])
   1436 
-> 1437     _, new_labels = algos.safe_sort(uniques, labels, na_sentinel=-1)
   1438     new_labels = _ensure_int64(new_labels)
   1439     new_left, new_right = new_labels[:l], new_labels[l:]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in safe_sort(values, labels, na_sentinel, assume_unique)
    483         except TypeError:
    484             # try this anyway
--> 485             ordered = sort_mixed(values)
    486 
    487     # labels:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in sort_mixed(values)
    469         str_pos = np.array([isinstance(x, string_types) for x in values],
    470                            dtype=bool)
--> 471         nums = np.sort(values[~str_pos])
    472         strs = np.sort(values[str_pos])
    473         return _ensure_object(np.concatenate([nums, strs]))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\conda_python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in sort(a, axis, kind, order)
    820     else:
    821         a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
--> 822     a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
    823     return a
    824 

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please no screenshots of the error -- copy the text and paste as a code block!

Comment: Ok, Done... Sorry for that

Comment: make sure that indices in merged DF's have the same dtypes

Comment: @MaxU Thanks a lot, I really found the `'Year'` column stored as `int64` in the first dataframe, and as `'object'` in the second dataframe. I will change the `int64` to `string` then will be back to you.

Comment: @MaxU I have changed the `'Year'` to`'str'` before setting it as index, then after setting the indeces, the error comes again, is there a way to convert the index `datatype` while it is index?

Comment: @MohammadElNesr, can you post an output of `df1.head()` __as text__ so we could copy and paste it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that indices in merged DF have different dtypes

Demo - how to convert string index level to `int`:

```
In [183]: df
Out[183]:
              0         1         2         3
bar 1 -0.205037  0.762509  0.816608 -1.057907
    2  1.249104  0.338777 -0.982084  0.329330
baz 1  0.845695 -0.996365  0.548100 -0.113733
    2  1.247092 -2.674061 -0.071993 -0.734242
foo 1 -1.233825 -0.195377 -0.240303  1.168055
    2 -0.108942 -0.615612 -1.299512  0.908641
qux 1  0.844421  0.251425 -0.506877  1.307800
    2  0.038580  0.045072 -0.262974  0.629804

In [184]: df.index
Out[184]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['1', '2']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

In [185]: df.index.get_level_values(1)
Out[185]: Index(['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2'], dtype='object')

In [187]: df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(1) \
                       .map(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')), level=1)
```

Result:

```
In [189]: df.index.get_level_values(1)
Out[189]: Int64Index([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

**UPDATE:** try this:

```
In [247]: d1 = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1jUsbr5pw6sUMvewI4fmbpssroG4RZ7LE&export=download', index_col=[0,1])

In [248]: d2 = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1Ufx6pvnSC6zQdTAj05ObmV027fA4-Mr3&export=download', index_col=[0,1])

In [249]: d2 = d2[pd.to_numeric(d2.index.get_level_values(1), errors='coerce').notna()]

In [250]: d2.index = d2.index.set_levels(d2.index.get_level_values(1).map(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')), level=1)

In [251]: d1.reset_index().merge(d2.reset_index(), on=['Country','Year'], how='outer').set_index(['Country','Year'])
Out[251]:
                            ind500  ind356  ind475  ind476        ind456
Country               Year
Afghanistan           1800   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1801   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1802   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1803   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1804   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1805   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1806   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1807   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1808   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
                      1809   603.0     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
...                            ...     ...     ...     ...           ...
Bahamas, The          1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  18381.131314
Gambia, The           1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    937.355288
Korea, Dem. Rep.      1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   1428.689253
Lao PDR               1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   1412.359955
Netherlands Antilles  1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  14076.731352
Russian Federation    1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  11794.726437
Serbia and Montenegro 1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   2987.080489
Syrian Arab Republic  1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   2015.913906
Yemen, Rep.           1967     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   1075.693355
Bahamas, The          1968     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  18712.082830

[46607 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I did it all, the datatypes of the indeces were changed successfuly, but unfortunately, the error still as is!! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the same error unfortunately! I have posted the links of two csv files in the question.

Comment: Are the posted CSV files in the question sufficient?

Comment: @MohammadElNesr, i missed that you have already posted links to those CSV's. Let me try it out...

Comment: STRANGE, I repeated the problem under `python 2.7`, it is solved, but under `python 3` the problem still exists. Is there any problem in `pandas` module of `python 3`?

Comment: @MohammadElNesr, what is your __Pandas__ versions for Python 2.7 and Python 3?

Comment: for python 3 '0.20.1' and for python 2 '0.21.1'

Comment: Many Thanks MaxU for your great help

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles across this in 2021:

The problem here is that the pandas multi-index is **not unique** in the dataset.

You can solve this either by:

- Selecting a unique multi-index
- Or, resetting the index and doing a merge on the columns

eg. `pd.merge(d1.reset_index(), d2.reset_index(), on=['Country','Year'], how='outer')`